# How to use SetViewFromArray correctly

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have two 3D points: target object's center, and camera position. I want to set a view as if I am looking at the object from the camera position.

I am struggling to figure out how to calculate View Parameters for setViewFromArray() function.

```
View parameters: [position-x, position-y, position-z, target-x, target-y, target-z, up-x, up-y, up-z, aspect, fov (radians), orthoScale, isPerspective (0=perspective, 1=ortho)]
```

I assumed 'position' means camera position, and 'target' is my object. Tried that but I couldn't get a proper view. I also have no idea what 'up' means.

Could someone explain it or share a sample code?

Thank you
Bandu

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the 'viewer.restoreState(JSON_OBJ)' method.

Specify the 'target object' and the position of your camera (the 'eye'), inside a JSON_OBJ object, and call restoreState.  You can specify other things like FOV and pivot-point, to get the look you want.

Here's a blog post with details: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/view-each-floor-using-vertical-explode

and here's a quick example, that specifies the target and eye and calls restoreState:

```
const JSON_OBJ = {"viewport":{"name":"",
    "eye":[-56.65177484061517,-110.22448381222459,48.75854608014884],
    "target":[-56.61241442215515,-110.13854629080645,48.725902642962545],
    "up":[0.13593096966393645,0.29678471606580187,0.9452203995872939],"worldUpVector":[0,0,1],
    "pivotPoint":[17.422795311668544,39.67309215526787,3.7083339691161967],"distanceToOrbit":172.6794473004014,
    "aspectRatio":1.9732770623333973,
    "projection":"perspective","isOrthographic":false,
    "fieldOfView":37.80748217565049}
}
        
viewer.restoreState(JSON_OBJ)
```

---

UPDATE:

But if you prefer to use `setViewFromArray`, then make sure to use `getViewArrayFromCamera` to grab the camera state array, like this:

```
    let cameraState = viewer.getViewArrayFromCamera()
    > [126.9228, -105.0679, 107.23, 116.13, -28.34, 33.9, 0, 0, 1, 1.90909, 0.761012]
```

Take the resulting array, and move the camera, like this:

```
    viewer.setViewFromArray([126.9228, -105.0679, 107.23, 116.13, -28.34, 33.9, 0, 0, 1, 1.90909, 0.761012])
```